# iOS 13 VoIP push notification - didReceiveIncomingPushWith not getting called when the application is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, voip, callkit

I am implementing a VoIP calling functionality in an iOS application. In the following method, I am immediately reporting an incoming call with CallKit:

**func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void)**

When the application is in the foreground or background, this method gets triggered and the call gets reported perfectly. However, when the application is terminated, this method does not get called at all.

If I run the application from XCode with the "Launch: Wait for the execurable to be launched" option added in the scheme, I can see, that something gets run when the VoIP push arrives, but not that method. Instead, I get a couple of seconds later the following message in the console: **Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9**

Any help/idea/input is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Additional information: this is what I have for "Background Modes".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to check Background processing in the background modes